# How to run function without interrupt the loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, parallel-processing, interrupt

I'm new to this community but I have some question.

I have loop that feel like this in my code. (not exactly like this)

```
count = 0
    while true
        a = 1
        if a < 10
            a = a+1
        end
        b = a;
        count = count +1
        if count == Sensor.Count
            a = a +10
            BotFusion(obj.BotFus,Likelihood); %my function that take long time to compute
            count = 0;
        end
        pause(0.1)
    end
```

I want to run my function without interrupt the process of my code.

The loop don't need to wait that function to complete.

I have been tried to run it parallel but, I got error when I `fetchOutput` form function.

Thank you in advance.

I have tired this. It don't have error messages now but, my figure not update and lag problems is not solved yet.

```
count = 0
        while true
            a = 1
            if a < 10
                a = a+1
            end
            b = a;
            count = count +1
            if count == Sensor.Count
                a = a +10
                x = parfeval(@BotFusion,0,obj.BotFus,Likelihood);
                fetchOutputs(x);
                count = 0;
            end
            pause(0.1)
        end
```

Comment: What have you tried to run your code in parallel? Have you tried [`parfeval`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/parallel.pool.parfeval.html)?

Comment: Yes, but when I use I got error massage when I `fetchOutputs` I'm not sure that what I have done was correct or not. Can `parfeval` and `fetchOutputs` use on handle class?

Comment: Hi Kantaphon, welcome to StackOverflow. "it's not works" is not a problem statement. Please [edit] your question to include a [mre]

Comment: MATLAB doesn’t support parallel in-process execution. All parallelism in MATLAB is based on spawning new processes (i.e. other instances of the MATLAB interpreter). So the best way to run your function in parallel is to start up a new MATLAB session to run that function. This is likely not what you’re trying to accomplish though. So please describe **why** you want to do this. Is it about UI interaction?

Comment: @SardarUsama I will edit it soon. Thank you.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes it's for UI interaction. I want to control my robot model that was on the figure while sensor on my robot update probability on the figure too. The part that take long time to compute is calculating new probability and update it on figure so, I want to run separately but I have no idea for now.

Comment: @CrisLuengo It seems that MATLAB has limited support for [thread workers](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/choose-between-thread-based-and-process-based-environments.html).

Comment: You can add `drawnow` calls inside your function to allow the UI to keep working. It interrupts the current function to handle UI callbacks, then continues the current function.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Can `drawnow` substitute with loop `set`? when both my loop and function need to update plot follow real time control. For now my code don't have an error it just have some lag when it call function. When I increase frequency lag got more serious. I will try out with your solution I get some idea now.
Sorry for my first question that so lag of infomation and thank you very much.

Comment: @Kantaphon-L: Not sure what you’re asking. You can `set` graphics properties of your plot, then call `drawnow` to have the plot updated.

Comment: @CrisLuengo For now, I use `set` and `line` to set and update is that similar?

Comment: Check the docs of [`fetchOutputs`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/parallel.future.fetchoutputs.html); it will wait until the calculation is finished. You should probably check if the calculation is finished before retrieving the results: https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/parallel.future.html#mw_12634ed2-ad41-4e29-847f-d6c212547237